# Wordpress templates and class methods

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

Is it possible to load a template file from a custom class (e.g. with the `page_template` hook) and be able to call methods of that class instance in the template? I know that I can call methods like `the_title()` from the template, but I cannot figure out if it is possible to call a custom class method directly from a template, even if that template has been loaded via that class.

In other words, is it possible to get the template file below to call the public method `callSomeClassMethodHere()` the same way I can call `the_title()`? I am beginning to think it is impossible.

#### CustomPluginTemplate.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
    <div>
        <p><?php callSomeClassMethodHere() ?></p>
    </div>
</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

#### CustomPlugin.php

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: My Custom Plugin
Description: This is a test plugin
Version: 0.0.1
*/

class CustomPlugin extends \WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'CustomPlugin', // ID
            __('Custom Plugin', 'text_domain'), // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'This is a custom plugin', 'text_domain' )) // Description
        );

        add_action('init', array($this, 'init'), 10, 0);
        add_filter('query_vars', array($this, 'query_vars'));
        add_action('page_template', array($this, 'page_template'));
    }

    public function init() {
        add_rewrite_rule(
            '^custom-page/([^/]*)',
            'index.php?page_id=2&custom_id=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );

    }

    public function query_vars($query_vars) {
        $query_vars[] = 'custom_id';

        return $query_vars;
    }

    public function page_template($path = '') {
        $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/CustomPluginTemplate.php';

        return $path;
    }
}

add_action('widgets_init', function () { register_widget('CustomPlugin'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call class method directly

```
$myPlugin = new CustomPlugin();
$myPlugin->page_template('your_path');
```

In this case hooks are used when you declare class, then you have to buld a method to return a template. You can use [load_template()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_template) function or [get_template_part()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still not able to access any class methods from the template. How does loading the template via `load_template` or `get_template_part` preserve the scope of `CustomPlugin`? Looking through the WP source code, I don't see anything other than globals.

Comment: @Andrew How do you include your class in the website? Is it a plugin, ot it's a *.php file included in functions.php ?